# Error in datarow,Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute

Tags: c#, foreach, datarow

I have for-each loop in which the data row is updated so the exception ,*Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute* is generated. any way to fix it? i have seen To-List function but it is not working with data row , here is my code:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows) {
  temp = row[0].ToString();
  foreach (DataRow rows in dataTable.Rows) {
    if (temp == rows[0].ToString()) {
      tempdatatable.Rows.Add(row[0],row[1]);
      dataTable.Rows.Remove(rows);
      //Update happens here
    }
    tempdatatable.DefaultView.Sort = "gscitations DESC";
    dataGridView1.DataSource = tempdatatable;
  }
}
```

Comment: try `for` instead of `foreach`

Comment: how , please help how can i use for loop i have tried but, data table can't be traverse through indexes

Comment: it surely can be!, http://stackoverflow.com/a/15457712/922198

Comment: It looks like this issue is specific to DataRowCollection.Remove() and is documented in Remarks in:
[DataRowCollection.Remove(DataRow) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcollection.remove?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Data.DataRowCollection.Remove);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this  :

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var tempRow = dataTable.Rows[i];
    var temp = dataTable.Rows[i][0];
    for (int j = 0; j < dataTable.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        DataRow rows = dataTable.Rows[j];
        if (temp == rows[0].ToString())
        {
            tempdatatable.Rows.Add(tempRow[0], tempRow[1]);
            dataTable.Rows.Remove(rows);      //Update happen here
        }
        tempdatatable.DefaultView.Sort = "gscitations DESC";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = tempdatatable;
    }
}
```

Comment: not working giving error of datatable in 2nd line, index cant b used with datatable

Comment: @mani - fixed, was a typo error!

Comment: @mani - 2nd & 3rd line are changed

Comment: A simpler way to resolve this is to change your dataTable.Rows to a dataTable.Select("") and you don't have to worry about creating for loops.  http://codingcramp.blogspot.com/2014/10/collection-was-modified-enumeration.html has a pretty good example.

Answer (score 11):

You cannot modify collection while enumerating it using Enumerator, which is happening behind the scene of the `foreach` statement ([MDSN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)).

One possible way to solve this problem is to collect rows to be deleted in the first enumeration and than remove them in the separate loop like this:

```
var rowsToDelete = new List<DataRow>();

foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
     {
         temp = row[0].ToString();
         foreach (DataRow rows in dataTable.Rows)
         {
             if (temp == rows[0].ToString())
             {
                 tempdatatable.Rows.Add(row[0],row[1]);
                 rowsToDelete.Add(rows);
             }
             tempdatatable.DefaultView.Sort = "gscitations DESC";
             dataGridView1.DataSource = tempdatatable;
         }
     }

rowsToDelete.ForEach( x => dataTable.Rows.Remove(x) );
```

You can also replace `foreach` loop with `for`, but you need to do extra work properly handling the current index while deleting the elements.

Comment: but if i remove that rows after the loop it will not be good, because i have 2.5 lac records if every time it finds match and donot remove it , it will search for it again and again so it will be time taking so i want it to remove the rows which matched

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you should make a separate  table of entries, and instead of calling datatable.Rows.Remove(rows), add the row "rows" to this other table. Then, whenever row or rows iterates, you run an if statement to check if its been "deleted", i.e., in the list of deleted rows. After the enumeration is over, you can then delete those rows permanently from the table.

**EDIT:**

Here's the code implementation:

```
DataTable duplicates = dataTable;
duplicates.Rows.Clear(); /* Produces an empty duplicate of the 
dataTable table to put the duplicates in */
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
     if (!duplicates.Rows.Contains(row))
     {    
         temp = row[0].ToString();
         foreach (DataRow rows in dataTable.Rows)
         {
             if (temp == rows[0].ToString()&&!duplicates.Rows.Contains(rows)) //need unique key
             {
                 tempdatatable.Rows.Add(row[0],row[1]);

             }
             tempdatatable.DefaultView.Sort = "gscitations DESC";
             dataGridView1.DataSource = tempdatatable;
         }
    }
}
foreach (DataRow row in duplicates.Rows)
{
    dataTable.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

if you don't have a unique key, you can try switching `!duplicates.Rows.Contains(/*specific row*/)` for `duplicates.Rows.IndexOf(/*specific row*/)>0`. That should provide an adequate substitute.

Comment: Try this short and simple solution, 

`foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Select(""))
 {
    if (row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("FilterDatabase"))
       dataTable.Rows.Remove(row);
  }`