# Cannot remove rows from DataTable because "Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute"

Tags: c#, datatable, datarowcollection

This is my code to remove row from datatable:

```
DataTable dtapple = dt;

foreach (DataRow drapplicant in dtapple.Rows)
{
    int iapp = Convert.ToInt32(drapplicant["SrNo"].ToString());

    if (drapplicant["PassportExpDate"].ToString().Trim() != "")
    {
        //ViewState["iapp"] = drapplicant;
        dtapple.Rows.Remove(drapplicant);
    }
}
```

Now when I use above code the row is removed, but after that I get an error

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute

I don't know exact reason.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in datarow,Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457571/error-in-datarow-collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-might-not-execut)

Comment: The solution in the linked question is horrible. With temp DataTables and nested loops :-\

Comment: Well, have you solved it yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code works for me :

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var tempRow = dataTable.Rows[i];
    var temp = dataTable.Rows[i][0];
    for (int j = 0; j < dataTable.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        DataRow rows = dataTable.Rows[j];
        if (temp == rows[0].ToString())
        {
            tempdatatable.Rows.Add(tempRow[0], tempRow[1]);
            dataTable.Rows.Remove(rows);      //Update happen here
        }
        tempdatatable.DefaultView.Sort = "gscitations DESC";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = tempdatatable;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You get this error because a collection must not change while iterating it. To remove some items from a collection you usually need a second collection that you iterate without changing it.

For your `DataTable` you need to get the rows you want to remove first and put them in a new collection. One way to achieve this is with `LINQ`:

Let's create some test data:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Test", typeof(bool));
DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
DataRow dr2 = dt.NewRow();
DataRow dr3 = dt.NewRow();

dr1["Test"] = true;
dr2["Test"] = false;
dr3["Test"] = false;

dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
dt.Rows.Add(dr2);
dt.Rows.Add(dr3);
```

then only get rows where value in the `Test` column is `false` and put them in a `List<DataRow>`:

```
var removeRows = 
    dt
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => (bool)r["Test"] == false)
    .ToList();
```

now you can itereate the new `removeRows` list and remove its items from the first collection (here `DataTable.Rows`)

```
// Remove selected rows.
foreach (var row in removeRows)
{
    dt.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

In your this query should work:

```
var removeRows = 
    dtapple
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => string.IsNullOrEmpty(r["PassportExpDate"].ToString()) == false)
    .ToList();
```

If you use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` there's no need to `Trim()` it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var tempRow = dataTable.Rows[i];
    var temp = dataTable.Rows[i][0];
    for (int j = 0; j < dataTable.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        DataRow rows = dataTable.Rows[j];
        if (temp == rows[0].ToString())
        {
            tempdatatable.Rows.Add(tempRow[0], tempRow[1]);
            dataTable.Rows.Remove(rows);      //Update happen here
        }
        tempdatatable.DefaultView.Sort = "gscitations DESC";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = tempdatatable;
    }
}
```

Comment: when loop is return again

Comment: This solution is horrible ;-) and it doesn't show that a second temp DataTable is necessary.