# Error occurred. Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute

Tags: c#

I am sorry to ask this question again, i was going thru other post related to this one but can't understand how to modify my code based on answers, so i post it here for help.

Following code throws the exception and i wast trying to modify my code like the one suggested in other post [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457571/error-in-datarow-collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-might-not-execut)

```
foreach (Assessment.tblMitchellLandscapeIDRow MitchellRow in objAssessment.tblMitchellLandscapeID.Rows)
{                                
     if (MitchellRow.AssessmentVersionID == AssessmentVersionID)
     DeleteMitchellLandscape(ref objAssessment, MitchellRow.MitchellID, UserFullname, ref ErrorMessage);
}
```

Comment: You cannot modify your collection (Your rows from tblMitchellLandscapeID) while iterating over it with a foreach statement. I guess that's what your Delete method is doing.

Comment: Use a `for` loop rather than a `foreach`. And iterate it in reverse if you are going to delete items from the list during the loop - it saves you from having to adjust your indexer.

Comment: The link you posted as for answers For loops not foreach.

Comment: If using a 'for' loop, remember to subtract one from the loop counter each time you delete a row.

Answer (score 1):

You can't alter a collection that you are iterating through.

As some commenter's have suggested, use a for loop, or build up a collection of the items you want to delete in the loop, then delete them afterwards. You might also need to modify your `DeleteMitchellLandscape` method.

```
var deleteList = new List<Assessment.tblMitchellLandscapeIDRow>();
foreach (Assessment.tblMitchellLandscapeIDRow MitchellRow in objAssessment.tblMitchellLandscapeID.Rows)
{                                
     if (MitchellRow.AssessmentVersionID == AssessmentVersionID)
         deleteList.Add(MitchellRow);
}

DeleteMitchellLandscape(ref objAssessment, deleteList, UserFullname, ref ErrorMessage);
```