# How can i change this LINQ query to use my List<int> instead of the hard coded number?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I finally got my LINQ to query the Datatable and with hard coded values, i get a new datatable with those records. But i need help to update this code to use my List returnClass() as my variables in the where clause.

```
var query = from r in d.AsEnumerable()
            where r.Field<string>("Column7") == "672"
            select r;

DataTable output = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
foreach (DataRow row in output.Rows)
{
    output.ImportRow(row);
}
```

Id like to replace the == "672" with the list i have that contains 94 values, that i want to exclude from the datatable.
This is my original post that got me to where i am now, but now i just need help with the LINQ query to use my List and write in a fashion that excludes any records that have the values in my list. Im trying to filter my 34k records down to 29k using that list.

Another example of something i tried that doesnt work

```
            var query = from r in d.AsEnumerable()
                    where !r.Field<string>("Column7").Contains(Convert.ToString(returnClass()))
                    select r;

        DataTable output = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
        foreach (DataRow row in output.Rows)
        {
            output.ImportRow(row);
        }
```

List looks like this(truncated for clarity)

```
    private List<int> returnClass()
    {
        List<int> cl = new List<int>();
        cl.Add(75);
        cl.Add(76);
        cl.Add(77);
        cl.Add(78);
        cl.Add(79);
        cl.Add(80);
        cl.Add(81);
        cl.Add(82);
        return cl;
    }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what your list could contain, and what the resulting query would look like?

Comment: is `myList` a list of strings, or ints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `myList` is a `List<string>`, you can try something like this:

```
var query = from r in d.AsEnumerable()
            where myList.Any(r.Field<string>("Column7").Contains)
            select r;
```

Or, if `myList` is a `List<int>`, you might want to modify your Database column to also have type `int`, and you can do the following:

```
var query = from r in d.AsEnumerable()
            where myList.Contains(r.Field<int>("Column7"))
            select r;
```

Comment: it complains about casting, my datatable seems to contain the values are strings and my list is of type Int, so do i need to convert  this line ?  r.Field<int>("Column7")

Comment: i get this error   Message "Specified cast is not valid." string
 on this line  where !returnClass().Contains(r.Field<int>("Column7"))

Comment: I went ahead and just changed my List to string values and updated my query to this and it seems to work..              var query = from r in d.AsEnumerable()
                        where !returnClass().Any(r.Field<string>("Column7").Contains)
                        select r;

            DataTable output = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
            foreach (DataRow row in output.Rows)
            {
                output.ImportRow(row);
            }

Comment: The above works until it gets to the line after my DataTable output where i start a foreach loop over the new datatable i get this error Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.

Comment: It throw the error on this line:  foreach (DataRow row in output.Rows)

Comment: @CubanGT The error "collection was modified" is because of this line `DataTable output = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();` See this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457571/error-in-datarow-collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-might-not-execut]

Comment: I changed my code to match the example, but my Row.Count seems to be growing, how or why is that possible?                  DataTable output = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
                for (int i = 0; i < output.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataRow rows = output.Rows[i];
                    output.ImportRow(rows);
                }